# The Right Word Redirects to Corresponding Page

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect, submit, inputbox

*I'd like to achieve the following with javascript:*

When you type any of the following words into the inputbox and click the submit button you'll be redirected to the corresponding page:

**tree** => tree.php
 
**chocolate** => chocolate.php
 
**bird** => bird.php
 
**candle** => candle.php
 
**apple** => apple.php

However if you type a different word than the above, you'll get a warning message.

```
<div id="main">
  <form action="">
    <ul>
      <li><input class="inputbox" type="text" name="TypeWord" value="" placeholder="Type a word here"/></li>
      <li><input class="button" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit word"/></li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="warning">
  <p style="visibility:hidden;">Oops, wrong word, please try again.</p>
</div>
```

Does anyone know of a javascript that can do this? Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: Well @jbyrne2007, if I had this javascript code, I wouldn't have to ask this question ;)

Comment: I didn't think you wanted someone to write it for you. See answer :)

Comment: I thought you didn't know the answer and wanted to make a fuss, but that was not your intention I see now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your just using pure javascript see this [fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/LXskB/)

```
var VArray = ["tree", "chocolate", "bird", "candle", "apple"];
```

see the code for yourself there but its easier to put everything you want to validate into an array and loop through that array.

Comment: Thanks for your help @jbyrne2007 :D There's only one little problem, it only works with the first word from the array (tree). All other words get a warning.